# Indentation is enumerate is messed up

Tags: indentation, enumerate

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{enumerate}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\declaretheoremstyle[spaceabove = 6pt, spacebelow = 6pt, headpunct={:} ,postfoothook=\noindent\hspace{-\fontdimen2\font}]{mydef}

\declaretheorem[parent=chapter,name = Def,style = mydef]{definition}
\renewcommand{\thedefinition}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{definition}}

\declaretheorem[numbered = no,style = mydef, name = Example]{example}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\declaretheorem[style=mydef,numbered=no]{remark}


\begin{document}
    \setcounter{chapter}{2}
    \chapter{Partial Differentiation}
    Contrary to the previous chapter, now we will discuss the continuity and differentiation of functions of several variables.
    \begin{definition}
        Let $D$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e: $$D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 = \{(x,y) \mid x\in \mathbb{R}, y\in\mathbb{R} \}$$
        We say that $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued function of two variables, if it assigns a real number $f(x,y)\, \mathrm{to\,each}\, (x,y) \in D.$ The \emph{range} of $f$ is the set of real numbers that $f$ maps to, $R\subseteq\mathbb{R}.$
    \end{definition}
    \begin{example}
        Let $f(x,y) = \sin(x^2y) \leadsto D = {\mathbb{R}}^2\, , R\rightarrow \left[-1,-1 \right] $
    \end{example}

    \begin{example}
        Let $f(x,y) = \ln\left[1-(x^2+y^2)\right]$\\ For $D:$ $$1-(x^2+y^2)>0$$
        $$(x^2+y^2)<1$$
        $$\Rightarrow D = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2+y^2<1\} =\text{An open disc of radius}\,\, 1\,\, \text{centered at} (0,0). $$
        For R: $$ z = 1-(x^2+y^2)\in (0,1] $$ 
        $$\Rightarrow \ln(z) \in (-\infty,0]$$ 
        $$\Rightarrow R = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid x\le0\}$$
    \end{example}
    The figures below show the domain, range, and the function itself.
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
            \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{UnitCircle_gr1.eps}
            \caption{D:\,$x^2+y^2\le1$}
        \end{subfigure}
        \,
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lnz_gr1.eps}
            \caption{R:\,$\ln(z)$}
            \label{fig:tiger}
        \end{subfigure}
        \,
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\textwidth}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{lnxy_gr1.eps}
            \caption{$\ln[1-(x^2+y^2)]$}
            \label{fig:mouse}
        \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{definition}
        A function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called \textit{continuous at $(a,b)\in D$} if
        \begin{equation}
            \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)=f(a,b) \tag{\ast}
        \end{equation}
        The function is called \textit{continuous} if it is continuous at every point in its domain $D$.
    \end{defintion}

    \begin{remark}
        $(\ast)$ Contains two requirements:
        \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
            \item $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)$ needs to exist.
            \item $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)$ has to be equal to $f(a,b)
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{remark}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is the second item in the list being created without an indent? How do I fix this?

Comment: Please always post a complete document that generates the problem, it is hard to debug fragments, especially fragments using environments not defined by default.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My mistake, I have updated the original post to the full tex document

Comment: The problem does not exists for me, the indentation is the same for the two items. Please post a minimal example, yours isn't minimal at all and won't compile correctly since some delimiters are missing, defintion insted of definition, etc.

Comment: Wow, it seems the error is removed when the typo is fixed. A silly error by me, apologies for the simple solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a missing `$` at the end of the second `\item`. It should be `... to $f(a,b)$`. Then it will be correct!

[image]

However, there are some other problems. marked by `%%!!`:

```
\begin{definition}
A function $f:D\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is called \textit{continuous at $(a,b)\in D$} if
\begin{equation}
    \lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)=f(a,b) \tag{$\ast$}%%!!!
\end{equation}
The function is called \textit{continuous} if it is continuous at every point in 
its domain $D$.
\end{definition}%%!! Was a typo here, missing i

\begin{remark}
$(\ast)$ Contains two requirements:
    \begin{enumerate}[(i)]
    \item $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)$ needs to exist.
    \item $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y)$ has to be equal to $f(a,b)$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

And, by the way, use `\[...\]` instead of `$$...$$`

Comment: One small question: On line 72 of my code where I have an \equation{end} within the definition of continuity, I'm getting multiple errors from "physics.sty" saying things like "Missing $ inserted" & "Extra }" & "Missing } inserted". However, the equation shows up properly in the pdf and nothing goes wrong in the actual output. I checked and I don't seem to be missing any delimiters, something seems to be clashing with the displaymath style of equation and something in this physics package.. but I'm not sure what it is

Comment: see edited answer ...

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense and solves all the issues. Okay I will use the square bracketing display math style from now on, but is there a specific reason? (just asking as I'm quite new to Latex so I'm not sure of all the intricacies)

Comment: In some cases there will be a wrong spacing